# Are the English language songs in "American Dad" sung in the viewer's native language when aired in non-English speaking countries?

Tags: distribution, dubbing, american-dad

For example: When American Dad is aired in Germany in German are the originally English-language songs such as "Is She Not Hot Enough" and "We've Been Bad" (Krampus and Steve's duet) sung in German?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. The songs remain in English, using the original voice track rather than rerecordings. They only add subtitles, often with a very rough 1:1 translation.

Also this is only done for original songs that are longer than just a few words. For example, Roger or Steve walking through a scene humming or singing a few words won't receive subtitles, if it's from some popular song and not original.

Overall, this isn't some general, unwritten rule or anything like that. Whether songs are translated and/or rerecorded often varies from show to show and sometimes even episode to episode (e.g. *The Simpsons* have many translated songs but also many that are only dubbed (in a really bad way).

Also keep in mind that many of these shows unfortunately don't have a prime time spot in Germany. Actually only *The Simpsons* airs new episodes at prime time, other series (like *American Dad*, *Family Guy*, etc.) are stuck on odd times or smaller, less popular stations, so they often have a smaller budget and getting songs translated right is often significantly more work (and therefore more expensive; I'm working as a translator).